# Remove list from list of lists, where only one element is known

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm not so much looking for just any solution (I have a working one displayed below), I'm more interested in knowing if there's a more efficient way of achieving this, maybe someway that does not require a standard for loop (?), although I understand a list comprehension may ultimately be the best solution.

This is a working example of what I want to achieve. The data used is just mock data for the purpose of displaying what I'm looking for, note the *first element is unique*, as with my real data, so I'm hoping this would provide a quicker way to target and delete the list for removal (the second element can be anything):

```
list_of_lists = [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A5', 16], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]

id_for_removal = 'A5'

for l in list_of_lists:
    if l[0] == id_for_removal:
        list_of_lists.remove([l[0], l[1]])
        
print(list_of_lists)
```

I haven't been able to find a question similar to this on here, but if it has been asked before let me know and I will delete my question.

*Note: It is my fault for not being clearer, but with the infrastructure I'm working with, using a dictionary is not an option for me unfortunately.

Comment: Use a dict `dict_of_lists = {'A1': ['A1', 2], ...}`? Or even just `{'A1': 2, ...}`. Does the list have to be ordered?

Comment: You have said that the first element in each sub-list is unique in which case your code would actually work. However, it is a general principle that you should not modify an iterable while you're iterating over it. Your code will not work as expected if you have two (or more) adjacent sublists where the first elements are equal and due for removal. Try your code with this list to see what happens: *[['A5', 1], ['A5', 2]]*. Using *filter()* is a nice way to do this but it's likely to be slower that a list comprehension

Comment: @DarkKnight I appreciate that feedback, you're dead right and it can be easily overlooked. As you stated, my code will work because of the unique values, but I may alter it all the same to be hardened to such an event because mistakes do happen and my dataset might be 'poisoned' by a bad element if I have mistakes elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your nested list to a dictionary:

```
list_of_lists = [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A5', 16], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]

id_for_removal = 'A5'

d= { k[0]: k[1:] for k in list_of_lists }

#{'A1': [2], 'A2': [2], 'A3': [8], 'A4': [43], 'A5': [16], 'A6': [16], 'A7': [32], 'A8': [36]}

del d[id_for_removal]

print(d)
#{'A1': [2], 'A2': [2], 'A3': [8], 'A4': [43], 'A6': [16], 'A7': [32], 'A8': [36]}
```

---

If you do not want to convert then you can use list comprehension but, **it will have a for loop**:

```
list_of_lists = [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A5', 16], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]

id_for_removal = 'A5'

print([lst for lst in list_of_lists if lst[0] != id_for_removal])
#[['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]
```

Comment: It is my fault for not being clearer, but with the infrastructure I'm working with, using a dictionary is not an option for me unfortunately. The list comprehension however may be my best option, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the first element is unique *and* you want to access items based on that first element, a `dict` mapping that first element to the whole item (or just the remaining element) might make more sense. You can create it from your list in a dict-comprehension and then `pop` the item directly.

```
dict_of_lists = {x[0]: x for x in list_of_lists}

id_for_removal = 'A5'
if id_for_removal in dict_of_lists:
    dict_of_lists.pop(id_for_removal)
```

(Of course, you should not create the dict just for popping the element, but replace your list with the dict entirely.)

Comment: It is my fault for not being clearer, but with the infrastructure I'm working with, using a dictionary is not an option for me unfortunately. I appreciate your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a loop, you can use the built-in filter method to get the list not containing the item you wish to remove.

```
list_of_lists = [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A5', 16], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]

id_for_removal = 'A5'

filtered_list = filter(lambda x: x[0] != id_for_removal, list_of_lists)

print(list(filtered_list))

# [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]
```

Another good option is to use the list comprehensions as you mentioned.

```
list_of_lists = [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A5', 16], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]

id_for_removal = 'A5'

updated_list = [item for item in list_of_lists if item[0] != id_for_removal]

print(updated_list)

# [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]
```

Comment: Why *list(updated_list)* when *updated_list* is already a list?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's already a list. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild your list using a list comprehension (with condition) as follows:

```
list_of_lists = [['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A5', 16], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]

id_for_removal = 'A5'

list_of_lists = [a for a in list_of_lists if a[0] != id_for_removal]

print(list_of_lists)
```

**Output:**

```
[['A1', 2], ['A2', 2], ['A3', 8], ['A4', 43], ['A6', 16], ['A7', 32], ['A8', 36]]
```